# iOS MMS mm7 reader

Tags: ios7, mms, mm7

I have troubles with a MMS sent through my application. The attachment of the MMS seems to be somehow messed up. Is there any way to extract the mm7 from the MMS or any xml format on iOS.
I know there are apps to do it on Android but what about iOS?

EDIT:
I'd love to get this kind of output out of my mm7/xml file, the smil...anything...

```
--34543345345435\r
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=us-ascii\r
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r
Content-ID: <mms7-submit>\r
\r
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
      <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4">657567567567</mm7:TransactionID>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
      <SubmitReq xmlns= "http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4">
        <MM7Version>6.8.0</MM7Version>
        <SenderIdentification>
          <VASID>#{vasid}</VASID>
          <VASPID>#{vaspid}</VASPID>
        </SenderIdentification>
        <Recipients>
          <To>
            <Number>+#{msisdn}</Number>
          </To>
        </Recipients>
        <ServiceCode>#{shortcode.to_s}</ServiceCode>
        <ApplicID>#{applicid}</ApplicID>
        <AuxApplicInfo>#{action}</AuxApplicInfo>
        <DeliveryReport>true</DeliveryReport>
        <Subject><![CDATA[#{subject.to_s}]]></Subject>
        <Content href="cid:myid.cidgeneric" allowAdaptations="false"/>
      </SubmitReq>
    </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
\r
--34543345345435\r
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="657567567567"\r
Content-ID: <myid.cidgeneric>\r
.....CONTENT...
--34543345345435\r
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show some code of how you are sending MMS. It will help people troubleshoot your issue

Comment: I'm not requiring any help about my code, just want to know if there is any tool able to extract xml\mm7 data from a MMS received on an iOS device :)

Comment: So you are looking for a tool to extract SMS/MMS from iOS device directly or from the iTunes backup files that is created? For example:  [How to extract text messages from iTunes backup to iPhone?](https://exploreb2b.com/articles/how-to-extract-text-messages-from-itunes-backup-to-iphone)  Are you looking for the tool  that runs on the device or on a computer? Mac? Windows?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's from the backup files or directly from the phone as long as I can access not only the text from the message but it's actual template/details -- see my edit above --. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

MM7 protocol is SOAP/HTTP based protocol used for communication between Value Added Service Provider (VASP) and MMSC (MMS Center). In MMS architecture, VASPs are server side applications sending messages to and receiving from handsets.

Client applications, like the one you're developing, should use MM4 protocol to communicate with MMSC.

```
(VASP) <-- MM7 --> (MMSC) <-- MM4 --> (handset)
```

MM4 consists of several types of binary encoded messages according to OMA MMS ENC specification. Transport is HTTP for send/receive and WAP push for delivery of notifications to a handset.